# jest/enzyme test failing although feature working

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

i'm learning unit testing for react with jest and enzyme. for the purpose of practice i built a simple to-do app and wrote tests for the different components.
the app and all it's features are working as intended without any bugs, but two out of seven of my tests for my app component (stateful) are failing. the two tests are for calling component methods.

here is the app component:

```
import React from 'react';
import InputField from '../components/InputField';
import Display from '../components/Display';
import ControlPanel from '../components/ControlPanel';

class App extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
      super()

      this.state = {
         newTask: '',
         allTasks: [],
         showAll: true,
      }
   }


   clearDisplay = () => {
      this.setState({
         newTask: '', 
         allTasks: [], 
         showAll: true,
      })
   }

   handleInputChange = (e) => {
      this.setState({newTask: e.target.value})
   }

   addTask = () => {
      if(this.state.newTask){
         let newTasksArray = [...this.state.allTasks, {text: this.state.newTask, status: true}];
         this.setState({
            allTasks: newTasksArray, 
            newTask: ''
         })
      }
   }

   toggleShow = (boolean) => {
      this.setState({showAll: boolean})
   }

   toggleTaskStatus = (index) => {
      let newTasksArray = [...this.state.allTasks];
      let changedTask = {...this.state.allTasks[index]};
      changedTask.status === true ?
         changedTask.status = false
         :
         changedTask.status = true;
      newTasksArray[index] = changedTask;

      this.setState({allTasks: newTasksArray})
   }

   deleteTask = (index) => {
      let newTasksArray = [...this.state.allTasks];
      newTasksArray.splice(index, 1);
      this.setState({allTasks: newTasksArray})
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div className='bg-gray-800 text-white min-h-screen'>
            <div className='mx-auto w-1/3'>
               <h1 className='uppercase text-2xl block font-bold py-6 text-gray-400 tracking-widest text-center'>
                  Todo List
               </h1>
               <InputField 
                  addTask={this.addTask} 
                  handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
                  inputValue={this.state.newTask}
               />
               <Display 
                  toggleTaskStatus={this.toggleTaskStatus} 
                  showAll={this.state.showAll} 
                  tasks={this.state.allTasks}
                  deleteTask={this.deleteTask}
               />
               <ControlPanel clearDisplay={this.clearDisplay} showAll={this.state.showAll} toggleShow={this.toggleShow}/>
            </div>
         </div>
      );   
   }
}

export default App;
```

the tests (for the sake of readability i removed all the passing tests):

```
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import React from "react";
import App from "../containers/App.js";

describe('App component', () => {

    it('addTask', () => {
        const mockState = {
            newTask: 'test',
            allTasks: [],
            showAll: true
        }

        const wrapper = shallow(<App {...mockState} />)
        const instance = wrapper.instance()

        instance.addTask()

        expect(wrapper.state().allTasks).toEqual([{status: true, text: 'test'}])
    })

    it('toggleTaskStatus', () => {
        const mockState = {
            newTask: '',
            allTasks: [{status:true, text:'test'}],
            showAll: true
        }

        const wrapper = shallow(<App {...mockState}/>)
        const instance = wrapper.instance()

        instance.toggleTaskStatus(0);
        expect(wrapper.state().allTasks[0].status).toBe(false)
    })

})
```

i assumed the issue comes from enzyme's abilty to deep compare, so i tried to write the expect logic in different ways, at first comparing the expected and recieved tests and later the arrays/objects themselves within the state, but so far with no success.

my question is how can (or should) i write the tests in order for them to pass and what am i doing wrong/missing here?

Comment: Try `wrapper = shallow(<App />)` and then `wrapper.setState(mockState)`

Comment: @WebbH that solved it! thank you! do you maybe care to explain why this works/solves the issue?

Comment: You were passing the mockState as a prop to the component rather than changing its state.